# birt Printing labels paper a4

Tags: printing, report, birt, label

I'm a newbye in Birt and I'd like to make a report for printing label on a "Printing labels paper" based on an A4 with 20 labels (5 row x 4 col).
I developed the report using 4 tables in a row and each table has a filter like that:

1. row[0]%4 eq 0        (filter of table 1)
2. row[0]%4 eq 1        (filter of table 2)
3. row[0]%4 eq 2        (filter of table 3)
4. row[0]%4 eq 3        (filter of table 4)

All seems to be ok but I need to insert an input parameter that will contains the starting row for the first page. 
Ex: user insert 5 as starting row and automatically the report will be start from 5th row of first page. If labels are much more than 4, report will generate the 2th page starting from 1st row and so on.
 
I tried to set margin on first page but I found the same margin in the next pages too.

Thanks
          
           GG

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty label just above your table, and add a script in the "onCreate" event of this label, to compute a margin dynamically:

```
var rowHeight=15;
this.getStyle().marginTop=(params["rowSkipNumber"].value*rowHeight)+"px";
```

Additionnally you may want to hide this label when the parameter is 0, in its "visibility" property with an expression such:

```
params["rowSkipNumber"].value==0
```